# C# How to add an element to List<string>?

Tags: c#, list, addition

How to add an element movie, to an existing category element? Currently im just able, to create new list entries on both fields.

```
class MovieSolver
    {
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public List<string> Movie { get; set; }
    }
```

```
class CreateMovieList
    {
        readonly static List<MovieSolver> playerTargetList = new List<MovieSolver>();

        public static void MovieCBO()
        {
            playerTargetList.Add(new MovieSolver { Category = "Action", Movie = new List<string> { "Taken", "The Factory", "Wind River" } });
            playerTargetList.Add(new MovieSolver { Category = "Comedy", Movie = new List<string> { "Gold", "Hangover", "We are the Millers" } });
            playerTargetList.Add(new MovieSolver { Category = "Thriller", Movie = new List<string> { "Jack Reacher", "Real Steel", "Iron Man I" } });
        }
    }
```

Beside is there a smarter way to create the `class MovieSolver`?

Comment: I assume your title is meant to be `List<string>`. Where does `List<List<int>>` come from. And what do you mean by 'smarter'?

Comment: Just not sure if i have done it the right way, as i have to to loop twice to access the List.

Comment: `public Dictionary<string,List<string>> playerTargetList;`

Comment: Three steps 1) Create top level elements  : List<List<int>> numbers = new List<List<int>>; 2) Create one dimensions list : List<int> number = new List<int>() { 1,2,3,4,5};  3) add one dimension list to two dimensional list numbers.Add(number);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, i cant find a int list here at all.

If you want to add a new string object to the List in a MoveiSolver object you first need to find the Moviesolver object were you want to add the new string element.

You can do this with a for loop, foreach loop or with LINQ.

foreach is often the most easy to understand for new coders.

```
Foreach item in playerTargetList
{
 if(item.category == "Action")
 {
  item.Movie.add("lorum ipsum");
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice and proper explanation, its working perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a default class like `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` here?

```
//Add library reference
using System.Collections.Generic;

public void MyMethod()
{
    //Initialize a Dictionary
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> MovieCBO = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    //Check if its an existing category
    //If its an existing category, add the movie to existing list
    if (MovieCBO.ContainsKey("some_category"))
    {
        MovieCBO["some_category"].Add("new_movie_name");
    }
    //If its a new category, add category along the movie
    else
    {
        MovieCBO.Add("some_category", new List<string>() { "new_movie_name" });
    }
}
```

All operations will be done in constant time. It would much faster than iterating through all the items in a list and checking the category.

Comment: Im currently trying to implement your solution, but i get no output, no error. I think is related to `if (MovieCBO.ContainsKey("some_category"))` . Should the if statement not be linked to `playerTargetList` This is actually what im currently trying to make the code work... I can accept just one answer. As soon your code above works im going to give you that tick.

Comment: What's the name of the dictionary you declared? if (<your_dictionary>.ContainsKey("key_value")) should be used.

Comment: i used your declaration `Dictionary<string, List<string>> MovieCBO = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();`

Comment: As i understood the logic, is if a category is existing it will add just the movie, else category and movie... the code its complete on my initial post, there is just a button to run `MovieCBO()` and `MyMethod()`

Answer (score 0):

You could add a method **addMovie** to class **CreateMovieList** that verifies if the MovieSolver doesn't exist yet and creates it if necessary

```
public static void addMovie(String category, String movie) 
{
    var movieSolver = playerTargetList.Find(e => e.Category == category);
    if(movieSolver != null) 
    {
        var existingMovie = movieSolver.Movie.Find( e => e == movie);
        if (existingMovie == null)
            movieSolver.Movie.Add(movie);
    }
    else
        playerTargetList.Add(new MovieSolver  { Category = category, Movie = new List<string> { movie } }); 
}
```

Comment: Exactly this i have done based on the input from @saratcsss. addMovie by using the Dictionary solution. Thanks for support